# To Shim or Not to Shim Underscore with Karma/Jasmine?

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, underscore.js, jasmine, karma-runner

How do I get Karama to play with backbone? All the docs I see you don't have to shim anything anymore, but I get errors whether I do or not. Karma is hosting my files and finding all the deps. I'm testing a Backbone app, *not an Angular app*. It seems that loading global `_` is the main problem currently.

**I've tried this shim in RequireJSConfig.js (loaded from Karma config) and I've also tried it without.**

```
        ...
        shim: {

           'underscore':{
            exports:'_'
           }
        ...
```

**I've confirmed the actual files are resolved by running Karma in debug mode:**

```
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
    C:/Users/vspazzy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
    C:/Users/vspazzy/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
    C:/workspace/das-web/src/test/RequireJSConfig.js
    C:/workspace/das-web/src/main/resources/js/lib-clean/backbone-1.1.2.min.js
    C:/workspace/das-web/src/main/resources/js/lib-clean/jquery-2.1.0.js
    C:/workspace/das-web/src/main/resources/js/lib-clean/require-2.1.1.full.js
    C:/workspace/das-web/src/main/resources/js/lib-clean/underscore-1.5.2.min.js
    ...
```

**This is my Karma.conf.js:**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({    

    basePath: 'src',        

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],    

    reporters: ["coverage"],

    preprocessors: {
      "**/*.js": "coverage"
    },

    files: [
        'test/KarmaUnitConfig.js',    

        // require, backbone, jquery and underscore
        {pattern: 'main/resources/js/lib-clean/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},

        // unit test helper
        {pattern: 'test/lib/testr.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},

        //the unit tests
        {pattern: 'test/js/unit/**/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},
        {pattern: 'test/js/unit/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},
        {pattern: 'test/js/helpers/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},

        // the app
        {pattern: 'main/**/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},

        // the stubs
        {pattern: 'test/js/stubs/**/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true}

    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
        //crappy cluttered lib folder
        'main/resources/js/lib/*.js',

        // avoid minified (it is  a package of whole application)
        'main/app.min.js',

        //ignore the old test html
        'main/test/integration.html',
        'main/test/integration.min.html',
        'main/test/unit.html',
        'main/test/unit.min.html',
        'main/test/unit-headless.html'

    ],

    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    singleRun: false,

      /*
      assuming these are deprecated because these are bundled now
      plugins: [
          'karma-requirejs',
          'karma-jasmine',
          'karma-chrome-launcher',
          'karma-firefox-launcher'
      ]*/

  });
};
```

**So, at this point Karma throws this error while running tests:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined
at http://localhost:9876/base/main/resources/js/lib-clean/backbone-1.1.2.min.js?69870e4d6c4da615282785f4b175f2dd9920d66a:219
```

--> on this line in backbone

```
 _.each(listenMethods, function(implementation, method) {
```